# React : How to avoid multiple function call

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, dom-events

I am working on small react project, actually I have some problem regarding to function call. I am updating the value of URL and invoke the method through button click to display updated values but whenever I click the button first it give me old values when I click again it give me updated values. Could someone please help me how to avoid old values on first click, I want to show updated values on first click not on second click. I am new to ReactJS , Could someone please help me how to fix this problem?

**Full Component Code**

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Item: 5,
      skip: 0
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  urlParams() {
    return `http://localhost:3001/meetups?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}`
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({skip: this.state.skip + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.urlParams()}>Example link</a>
        <pre>{this.urlParams()}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change link</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.querySelector('div#my-example' ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State is not `updating` at time when **urlParams** is being called. As @jolly told you `setState` is **Asynch** function so it's better to use it in a `callback` or you may simply pass your **sortedData** type as in argument in **getSortedType** function instead of updating state. Also, ReactJS community suggests or the best practice is to use `state` only if `props` are needed to be `updated`.

In case, if you dont feel comfortable with CB. you may use **setTimeOut** which I think is a bad practice but it would solve your problem. your code would be like:

```js
getSortedData=()=>{
    this.setState({sortedData:'name desc'});
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.getData();
    }, 200);
}
```

Comment: Thank You ,It working !! . Actually I want more , I want to make logic if User click first time I want to update it with `name asc` , when User click second time I want to update it with `name desc` . It will repeat same manner when ever user click . I am beginner could you please help me ?

Comment: Don't hold against me @fahad tufail, but please, don't use `setTimeout()` like that: it may works but it's really not a good way to do that, not at all.
For the second question you asked, look at my answer below, I add there the code (it would be "bad to see" here in comment)

Comment: @Jolly, I totally agree using setTimeOut is not a good practice at all. but for him it solves his problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's quite lots of code e no working example, so I may be wrong, but I think the problem is in `getSortedData()`: in that function, you call `setState()` and right after you call `getData()` which will perform a fetch, which uses `ulrParams()` function, which uses property `this.state.sortedData`.

The problem in this is that `setState()` is async, so it's not sure that, when `urlParams()` uses `this.state.sortedData`, the property is updated (actually, we are sure it's not updated).

Try to rewrite `getSortedData()` as follow:

```
getSortedData =() => {
    this.setState({sortedData:'name desc'}, () => {
        this.getData();
    })
}
```

What I'm doing here is passing a callback to `setState()`: doing this way, `getData()` will be called AFTER you've updated the state.

---

Regarding the question you asked in the comment, if you want to toggle the order, you can add a property `order` in the state of the Component, assigning to it a default value `'name desc'`.
Then, you change `getSortedData` as follow:

```
getSortedData =() => {
    let newSort = 'name asc';
    if (this.state.sorteData === newSort) 'name desc';

    this.setState({sortedData: newSort}, () => {
        this.getData();
    })
}
```